# SQL: How to find the records with more than an hour between them

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a MYOB database in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have two tables, `SALESORD_HDR` and `SALESORDHIST`. For each record in `SALESORD_HDR`, there is several records in `SALESORDHIST`. I want to count the number of records (sasles orders) in the hdr table, that have more than an hour between the first instance of a record in the hist table that has status 'R', and the last record that has status 'I'. Here's some sample data:

Table headers:

```
SALESORD_HDR: SEQNO(pk, int), STATUS(varchar(1)), ORDERDATE(datetime)
SALESORDHIST: SEQNO(pk, int), HEADER_SOURCE_SEQNO(from alesord.seqno), EVENT_TYPE(varchar(1)), HISTDATETIME(Datetime)
```

Data in `Salesordhist`:

```
    SEQNO   HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ   EVENT_TYPE  HISTDATETIME
    1069559 435015  N   01:15.0
    1069560 435015  O   01:15.0
    1069561 435015  O   01:15.0
    1069562 435015  R   01:16.0---
    1069563 435015  R   01:16.0
    1069586 435015  I   02:24.0
    1069587 435015  I   02:24.0---
```

Data in `Salesord_hdr`:

```
SEQNO   STATUS  ORDERDATE
435114  2   2014-01-29 00:00.0
```

So, I want to return the count of orders that have more that an hour between the two lines marked --- in their related salesordhist lines. The common identifier is the `SEQNO` in `SALESORD_HDR` is in `HEADER_SOURCE_SEQNO` in `SALESORDHIST`

I have a suspicion I need to create a temporary table to do this one, but I'm out of my league here.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `header_source_seq` identifies an order.  The following gets the count:

```
select count(*)
from (select header_source_seq, 
             min(case when event_type = 'R' then histdatetime end) as rdt,
             max(case when event_type = 'I' then histdatetime end) as idt
      from salesordhist soh
      group by header_source_seq
    ) t
where idt >= rdt + 1/24.0;
```

The subquery finds the orders (`header_source_seq`s) with the associated times.  The outer query simply counts them subject to the condition.  In SQL Server, adding a number to a `datetime` is interpreting as adding that many days.  An hour is `1/24.0` days.

EDIT:

For today's orders, we'll need to join in the header table after all:

```
select count(*)
from (select header_source_seq, 
             min(case when event_type = 'R' then histdatetime end) as rdt,
             max(case when event_type = 'I' then histdatetime end) as idt
      from salesordhist soh join
           salesord_hdr hdr
           on soh.header_source_seq = hdr.seqno
      where hdr.orderdate >= cast(getdate() as date)
      group by header_source_seq
    ) t
where idt >= rdt + 1/24.0;
```

Note that this uses the condition:

```
      where hdr.orderdate >= cast(getdate() as date)
```

First, I'm assuming there are no future orders.  If that's wrong, it is easily fixed.  Second, the `orderdate` column is *not* in a function.  This allows an index on the column to be used.  Third, the time is truncated by converting to a `date`.

Comment: OK, this gives me a large number, which is every invoice in the database with more than an hour between go and whoa. Good. Now, I want to check for it if it is today only. Where do i slip the `datediff(d,0,getdate()) `to select the day?

Comment: @Bevan . . . In the subquery.

Comment: YAY! I just changed the cast date bit to datediff, and bingo! for those who want the completed code, here it is: `select COUNT(*)
from (select header_source_seq, 
             min(case when event_type = 'R' then histdatetime end) as rdt,
             max(case when event_type = 'I' then histdatetime end) as idt
      from salesordhist soh join
           salesord_hdr hdr
           on soh.header_source_seq = hdr.seqno
      where hdr.orderdate >= DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())
      and hdr.STATUS = 2
      group by header_source_seq
    ) t
where idt >= rdt + 1/24.0;`

Comment: And we used that to check if a product code that is for urgent freight, was processed within 10 minutes, by doing this:`select COUNT(*) from (select header_source_seq, min(case when event_type = 'R' then histdatetime end) as rdt, max(case when event_type = 'I' then histdatetime end) as idt from salesordhist soh join salesord_hdr hdr on soh.header_source_seq = hdr.seqno join SALESORD_LINES sol on soh.HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ = sol.HDR_SEQNO where hdr.orderdate = DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()) and hdr.STATUS = 2 and sol.STOCKCODE = 'DP90' group by header_source_seq) t where idt >= rdt + 1/144.0;`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SEQNO, COUNT(*)
FROM SALESORD_HDR NATURAL JOIN /* on SEQNO */
(SELECT SEQNO, 
        HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN STATUS='R' THEN HISTDATETIME ELSE NULL END) AS RTIME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS='I' THEN HISTDATETIME ELSE NULL END) AS ITIME)
 FROM SALESORDHIST
 GROUP BY SEQNO, HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ)
 AS TIME_SUBQUERY
WHERE ITIME IS NOT NULL AND RTIME IS NOT NULL 
AND datediff(hour, RTIME, ITIME) > 1 /* check your favorite DB's date arithmetic commands */
GROUP BY SEQNO;
```

I don't know your database system, so its INTERVAL notation or timestamp subtraction command may be different. And I am not sure I understand the relationship between the two tables and what you want counted. But the `MIN` and `MAX` trick should get you through without a temp table and with only one pass through `SALESORDHIST`.

I can think of other ways to do this if the large table is indexed; if there are a lot of records multiple queries per group might work better than the table scan I expect this to generate.

**UPDATE:** changed from Postgres `INTERVAL` date arithmetic to `datediff`

Comment: sql server 2008 does not have "INTERVAL 1 HOUR" -- that is DB2 or Oracle I believe

Comment: @Hogan, I generally use Postgres. But SQL Server must have something similar, that isn't going to be an issue.

Comment: This goes "incorrect syntax' and gripes about the join. What happens, is that every time an order gets acted upon, each line item in that order is entered as a history event in the hist table. So, my example ordewr contained two items, and was processed in just over an hour between 'Release' - R in the table, and 'Invoiced' - I in the table. So, I want this record to be counted as 1 (i want a total of orders not processed within an hour)

Comment: SQL server may not like NATURAL JOIN, replace with `JOIN` and an `ON TIME_SUBQUERY.SEQNO=SALESORD_HDR.SEQNO` . (I've also been known to mismatch parentheses)